# heroku remote branch

Tags: git, heroku

i have really annoying problem,  i deleted my former acount on heroku with all the apps, then i created a new one ,
i wanted to add remote branch to git and then the problems started.

```
git remote -v 
heroku  git@heroku.com:freezing-moon-116.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:freezing-moon-116.git (push)
origin  git@gitbus.fiit.stuba.sk:laser_kn/laser_kn.git (fetch)
origin  git@gitbus.fiit.stuba.sk:laser_kn/laser_kn.git (push)

git remote rm heroku 
error: Could not remove config section 'remote.heroku'


vim .git/config
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@gitbus.fiit.stuba.sk:laser_kn/laser_kn.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

My question is how can i remove that broken remote heroku repo and add a new one ?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `git remote` shows you the remote but `.git/config` does not, it seems like that remote is defined in another config file.

To quote `man git config`:

```
FILES
       If not set explicitly with --file, there are three files where git
       config will search for configuration options:

       $GIT_DIR/config
           Repository specific configuration file. (The filename is of course
           relative to the repository root, not the working directory.)

       ~/.gitconfig
           User-specific configuration file. Also called "global"
           configuration file.

       $(prefix)/etc/gitconfig
           System-wide configuration file.
```

Have a look at `~/.gitconfig` most likely you should find your remote there.